# Why nothing is printed on the console?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I create 2 methods that print x and y 100 times. I want them to run concurrent and I expect the output to be xxxxyxyxyyyxyyxyx...  sthg like that.
It doesn't print anything. Am I missing some logic here?

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication32
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static async Task<int> Print1()
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write("x");
                }
            });

            return 1;
        }

        public static async Task<int> Print2()
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write("y");
                }
            });

            return 1;
        }

        public static void Run()
        {
            Task<int> i = Print1();
            Task<int> k = Print2();
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you just attach the debugger and see?

Comment: `Program` stars two tasks in child threads and immediately ends, ending all it's child threads, so both `Print` never run. Wait for the tasks to end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not waiting for the tasks to complete, hence the program is terminating (no more synchronous code blocking).

If you want the tasks to run concurrently, do this instead:

```
public static void Run()
{
    Task<int> i = Print1();
    Task<int> k = Print2();
    Task.WaitAll(i, k);
}
```

The other way to wait for this tasks to complete, would be to do this:

```
public static async Task Run()
{
    Task<int> i = Print1();
    Task<int> k = Print2();
    await Task.WhenAll(i, k);
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Run().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Comment: I tried what you said but this time methods processed sequentially. Output: xxxxxxxx(100 times)yyyyyyy(100 times). I need output to be like xxxxyyxyxyxyxyxyyyx...

Comment: No they didn't @Lyrk . They just happened to run in sequence. Your tasks aren't doing a lot, meaning they will write extremely fast meaning that the first one will probably finish before the second is even initialised. They're still running on independent threads

Comment: To back what @Liam said, you could add a `await Task.Delay(10);` inside the `Print1` loop

Comment: To state the obvious, this is all pretty pointless (I'm guessing your just testing Task). You'd never do this in real life. This is likely the least efficient way to write stuff to the console.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I did what you said and it prompted me to make lambda expression as async too. I made lambda expression as async then run the program. Yes it is working as I wanted  but then as a test I deleted "Task.WaitAll(i,k)" portion from the code and it gave me the same result. When I put a delay inside the for loop, I dont need to wait for all tasks to finish?

Comment: @Lyrk That depends, did you add anything to make the program wait, like what Andrei Matracaru suggests in his answer? `Task.WaitAll` here (and when used as I wrote) will make a synchronous, blocking wait, so that the program won't continue while waiting

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/z2Xt5U      In here I copy paste my last code. In here I did not used Task.WaitAll(i,k). Is this really necessary? Why I am asking is I dont need these two tasks ending to be known to me. One can finish earlier and other can finihs later. All I want to achieve is they run concurrently.

Comment: @Lyrk you did add `Console.ReadLine()` to the `Main` method, that's why you don't need to use `Task.WhenAll`. Do note that it's not needed only because of the blocking `ReadLine` call; in a real-world application you wouldn't likely be able to use it

Comment: Ah okay. Thank you sir for your patience. I unserstood now.

Comment: Doesn't anyone dare to comment on the downvote? 6 downvotes and not a single comment?

Answer (score 12):

## Explanation

There are a couple things we need to tweak to get the desired output: `xxxxyxyxyyyxyyxyx`.

1. The `Run` method is not waiting for `Task i` and `Task k` to finish

   - This means that the console application will close before the two `Task`s complete
   - As [Andrei Matracaru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6139866/andrei-matracaru) mentions in his answer, if you add `Console.ReadLine()`, it will prevent the console application from closing before the strings have been printed to the screen.
   - A more elegant solution is to use `Task.WhenAll`. `Task.WhenAll` will allow the code yield to its calling thread (in this case, the Main Thread) which doesn't freeze the UI of the application, and allows the application to continue to print to the screen until the `Task`s have completed. This may seem trivial for a simple console app, but it is crucial to never lock up the Main Thread when building any user-interactive application like mobile or web applications; locking up the Main Thread is what causing apps to "freeze".
   - [Camilo Terevinto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3932049/camilo-terevinto)'s answer above recommends `Task.WaitAll`. This is also bad practice because it will also freeze the application; `Task.WaitAll` is not awaitable and cannot not yield to the calling thread.
2. `Print1()` and `Print2()` never yield to the Main Thread

   - These methods are executing on a background thread, but they don't include an `await` inside of the `for loop`
   - An `await` is necessary inside of the `for loop` to allow CPU to continue executing the Main Thread, because `Console.Write()` can only print to the screen on the Main Thread.

## Code

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication32
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static async Task<int> Print1()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("x");
                await Task.Delay(10);
            }

            return 1;
        }

        public static async Task<int> Print2()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("y");
                await Task.Delay(10);
            }

            return 1;
        }

        public static async Task Run()
        {
            var i = Print1();
            var k = Print2();

            await Task.WhenAll(i, k);
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Run(async () => await Run()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
    }
}
```

## Output

> xyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxxyxyxyxy
>   Press any key to continue...

## C# 7.1 Alternative

C# 7.1 introduces the ability to have an `async Main` method. This means that we can tweak the `Main` method as follows:

```cs
    ...

    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await Run();
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Amazing that you made an answer out of my comment to use `Task.Delay` and got more upvotes... `Task.Run(async () => await Run()).Wait();` is a double wrap-around, you could just do `Run().Wait()`. You also failed to mention that only Visual Studio 2017 Preview 3 can run c# 7.1 code

Comment: Instead of using `.Wait()` or `.Result`, I'd strongly recommend to use `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead as it gives better stack traces when something throws an exception.

Comment: Additional bonus material about console apps and thread affinity: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/01/20/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/

Answer (score 5):

Tried your code and works just fine. Probably you think it doesn't work because the console window closes very fast. Add a `Console.ReadLine()` in your Main:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Run();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```